# Rendering a Loading Bar in React

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I have a state in my component `progress` and I am confused about when is the best time in the lifecycle to update the `progress` state I am making an http request promise in `componentDidMount()`. So I would like the progress bar to be rendering while the data is not ready to be rendered.

I am using Axios to make the request and I am creating a couple of bluebird Promises inside that request.

At the end I update the `progress` state to 100,

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/property/documents.json')
        .then((res) => {
            // save an object with the variable representation of the variable and the string
            // this will allow a forEach loop for teh promises of data
            let complianceStatus = {
                needsUploading: 'needsUploading',
                pendingApproval: 'pendingApproval',
                approved: 'approved'
            }

            function filterer(status, target) { return status === target }

            for(let status in complianceStatus) {
                let current = status;
                Promise.map(res.data.compliance, (record) => {
                    return Promise.all([filterer(record.type, complianceStatus[status]), record]);
                }).then((values) => {
                    status = values.filter((value) => {
                        return value[0] == true
                    }).map((value) => {
                        return value[1];
                    });
                    this.setState({ [complianceStatus[current]]: status })
                })
            }
            // general data 
            Promise.map(res.data.general, (record) => {
                    return record;
                }).then((generalDocs) => {
                    this.setState({ generalDocs })
                })
        }).then(() => {
            this.setState({ progress: 100, isLoading: false });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

My `<ProgressBar percent={ this.state.progress } autoIncrement={ true } spinner={ false } />`is just sitting in my return of the render method.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of the component, and let us know what framework you are using to make the http request

Comment: @MichaelPeyper Sure 1 sec

Comment: @MichaelPeyper thanks for helping Michael, please let me know any more information you may need.

Comment: @Sequential - can you not use the `progress` callback provided by `axios`? https://github.com/qiangmao/axios#request-config

Comment: @fubar never used this, trying to implement now.

Comment: @fubar Awesome direction, and that's great to know, but the majority of the load time is coming from the filtering after the data has been downloaded. So this seems to fire twice within 500ms, but the total process is about 5 seconds. I used onDownloadProgress.

Comment: 5 seconds! Wow. Can you not move that logic to the server side and likely cache the data? But in answer to your question, I do not think there's going to be a way to show the filtering progress, as you have no metric for determining the time required.

Comment: You could implement a dirty solution whereby you update the progress by say 50% when downloading the data, and then use an interval timer to update the remaining 49% over the course of 5 seconds, unless the promise finishes before, in which case you advance to 100% and clear the interval timer.

Comment: @fubar That's what I thought, I am pretty sure my greatest issue with my code is I setState after every promise in the for Loop, I think it would be way more efficient if I setState in a wrapping promise: which is what I am working on now. Poor planning :/

Comment: @fubar I may have to do something like that. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it, you have been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be super-accurate, but you can make something that shows the user that progress is happening, and gives a rough idea of the progress so far.  I've extracted progress bar update logic into another function on the class:

```
getProgressUpdater() {
    let maxTicks = 0;
    let currentTick = 0;
    let isTicking = false;

    const setTick = ( progress ) => {
        this.setState({ progress });
    }

    const tick = () => {
        setTick(++currentTick);
        if( currentTick < maxTicks ) {
            isTicking = true;
            setTimeout(tick, 100);
        } else {
            isTicking = false;
        }
    }

    const setMaxTicks = ( progress ) => {
         maxTicks = progress;
         if (!isTicking) {
             tick();
         }
    }

    const incrementMaxTicks = ( increment ) => {
         maxTicks += increment;
         if (!isTicking) {
             tick();
         }
    }

    return {
         setMaxTicks,
         incrementMaxTicks,
         setTick
    }
}
```

Which you could use throughout your async calls to give progress updates:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const progressUpdater = this.getProgressUpdater();
  progressUpdater.setMaxTicks(10);
  axios.get('/api/property/documents.json')
    .then((res) => {
        // save an object with the variable representation of the variable and the string
        // this will allow a forEach loop for teh promises of data
        let complianceStatus = {
            needsUploading: 'needsUploading',
            pendingApproval: 'pendingApproval',
            approved: 'approved'
        }

        function filterer(status, target) { return status === target }

        for(let status in complianceStatus) {
            progressUpdater.incrementMaxTicks(25);
            let current = status;
            Promise.map(res.data.compliance, (record) => {
                return Promise.all([filterer(record.type, complianceStatus[status]), record]);
            }).then((values) => {
                status = values.filter((value) => {
                    return value[0] == true
                }).map((value) => {
                    return value[1];
                });
                this.setState({ [complianceStatus[current]]: status })
            })
        }


        progressUpdater.setMaxTicks(90)

        // general data 
        Promise.map(res.data.general, (record) => {
                return record;
            }).then((generalDocs) => {
                this.setState({ generalDocs })
            })
    }).then(() => {
        progressUpdater.setTick(100);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```